# Its a program using a bitwise operators

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

The number of can types to be distinguished is N, and each can has L types of characteristics that can be answered with 1 or 0. Your objective is to distinguish between all N types of can by memorizing the characteristics of as few of the L types as possible.
All test cases satisfy the following conditions:

- 2 ≤ N ≤ 100
- 1 ≤ L ≤ 8・0 ≤ X_{i, j} ≤ 1(1 ≤ i ≤ N
- 1 ≤ j ≤ L)

definitely distinguishable.

```
using System;

namespace CanDistinguisher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read the number of can types and number of features
            string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            int N = int.Parse(input[0]);
            int L = int.Parse(input[1]);

            // Read the answers to the questions for each feature
            int[,] cans= new int[N, L];
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                for (int j = 0; j < L; j++)
                {
                    cans[i, j] = int.Parse(input[j]);
                }
            }

            // Find the minimum number of features required to distinguish all N types of can
            int result = L;
            for (int i = 0; i < (1 << L); i++)
            {
                int[] group = new int[N];
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < L; k++)
                    {
                        if (((i >> k) & 1) == 1)
                        {
                            group[j] |= (cans[j, k] << k);
                        }
                    }
                }
                bool flag = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++)
                    {
                        if (group[j] == group[k])
                        {
                            flag = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (flag)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < L; j++)
                    {
                        if (((i >> j) & 1) == 1)
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    result = Math.Min(result, count);
                }
            }

            // Output the result
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

In this program I did not understand the logic. If someone can help me understand the logic. For example why are they doing this particular line.

```
if (((i >> k) & 1) == 1)
{
    group[j] |= (cans[j, k] << k);
}
```

I still don't understand the bitwise operators and its use cases. If someone can help me understand the complete code and its logic would be very helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the whole thing, but this particular if-condition tests single bits of `i`. The the bits are numbered from 0 to 31 from right to left. It tests the bit number k by shifting it k positions to the right and then masking it with 1. If the result is 1 the bit is 1 and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I could understand that much but I do not know how this code snippet help in overall code. But thank you your efforts.